# Автоотключение сервера Apache24 при первом чистом запуске

Tags: php

Решил попробывать себя в PHP и просто в вебе. Для чего решил изучить php на metanit (ссылка: https://metanit.com/php/tutorial/1.3.php), когда дошла очередь до запуска только что распокованного httpd.exe то через секунду после запуска тот создав чёрное консольное окно тут же отключаеться.
Сначало я подумал, что дело в архиве и скачал новый. Ситуация не изменилось. Потом решил что дело в настрйке. Настроил, результат тот же ... как лечить ?

Comment: Запустите через командную строку и прочитайте, на что ругается

Comment: @andreymal подскажите как это сделать ?

Comment: @andreymal попытался сам ... вывело "httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 39 of E:/Code/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory"

Comment: Вот вам и ответ, чините конфиг

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за помощь, исправил :)